# How to set the background color of a button using a layout as the background

Tags: java, android, android-layout, xamarin, android-button

layout_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <!--<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />-->
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

main_activity.xml

```
<ImageButton
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
            android:src="@drawable/myicon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tint="@android:color/black"
            android:minWidth="80.0dp"
            android:minHeight="80.0dp"
            android:padding="10px"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/btnFoo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="91.0dp" 
           />
```

I am setting the background of my `ImageButton` to a layout so I can have dynamic rounded corners as you can see in this image:

[image]

However, I need to change the background color of just that button to another solid color such as red.

If I set the background color with `btnFoo.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red)`, then the rounded corners are gone.

I assume because it overwrote the background attribute to be a solid color value rather than the `layout_bg.xml` file.

How can I set the background color of this specific `ImageButton` and not all the ImageButtons in my main_activity that use `layout_bg` as the background?

Comment: You need to make another drawable with the color Red then use it : btnFoo.SetBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_drawable);

Comment: @WowoOt not ideal, but works. Its a faster solution than the problems the MaterialButton answer has given me below so post the answer if you want me to accept it.

Comment: @John You don't need to create another drawable. Just apply a `colorFilter`. Check the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63495683/2016562).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make another drawable with the color Red then use it :

```
btnFoo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

use material button all functionality is built in already

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
              android:layout_width="size"
              android:layout_height="size"
              android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
              android:text="Add Images"
              android:textAllCaps="false"
              android:textColor="@color/white"
              app:cornerRadius="20dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
    btnFoo.background.colorFilter =
        BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(
            color, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP)
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires `androidx.core:core:1.2.0`

As alternative you can use the `MaterialButton` :

```
   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:iconSize="48dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/..."
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:cornerRadius="10dp"/>
```

In this case just use:

```
button1.backgroundTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color....)
```

[image]